# Options not working if custom class is in subfolder

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

I have created my own LaTeX template and use a custom class for this purpose. I developed the template on a Windows machine using TeX Live 2020 and recently compiled a copy of the project on my Mac. However, on the Mac with MacTeX 2020, errors occurred that I could trace back to the options not working. Further attempts to pinpoint the problem showed that the options only don't work if the class is in a subfolder. If it is in the root directory, then it works fine. I also noticed that the error only occurs when the native LaTeX compilers are used. In Texpad the error does not occur.

The following files should illustrate the errors as a minimal example. For all those who can't run it themselves due to system requirements, I show the outputs of the respective document generation steps.

---

`testclass.cls` and `testfolder/testclass.cls`

```tex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[testclass]
\LoadClass{article}

\newif\if@testOpion
\@testOpiontrue

\DeclareOption{optionTrue}{\@testOpiontrue}
\DeclareOption{optionFalse}{\@testOpionfalse}

\ExecuteOptions{optionTrue}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\newcommand{\printtestresult}{}
\if@testOpion
    \renewcommand{\printtestresult}{true}
\else
    \renewcommand{\printtestresult}{false}
\fi

\endinput
```

`test.tex`

```tex
\documentclass[optionFalse]{testclass} % works
% \documentclass[optionFalse]{testfolder/testclass} % does not work

\begin{document}
   \texttt{testOption} is set to \texttt{\printtestresult}
\end{document}
```

Project structure

```
test_project
├── test.tex
├── testclass.cls
└── testfolder
    └── testclass.cls
```

---

When creating the document with `\documentclass[optionFalse]{testclass}` I get the following outputs:

- Windows:

  - `testOption` is set to `false`
- Mac:

  - Texpad:

    - `testOption` is set to `false`
  - native compiler:

    - `testOption` is set to `false`

If, however, I use the nested class `\documentclass[optionFalse]{testfolder/testclass}`, the following happens:

- Windows (native):

  - `testOption` is set to `false`
- Mac

  - Texpad:

    - `testOption` is set to `false`
  - native compiler:

    - `testOption` is set to `true`

---

Feel free to ask for more information if I have forgotten anything important. I find it quite difficult to explain this bug clearly, as it is not really tangible for me. What I can say, though, is that the same bug occurs on a friend's brand new Mac, which has a fresh MaxTeX installation on it. So it seems not to be a problem with my distribution.

Comment: `\documentclass` doesn't take a path but only the name provided by the class itself. In order to let latex find your class file, you have to either move the file to your local texmf-tree or add the subdirectory to your path (you can use the TEXINPUTS variable for that)

Comment: this should be resolved in the latex version, see e.g. https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/422

Comment: @DG' I understand, but as already stated in the issue posted by Ulrike, I, too, want to have a portable template that I can easily share with colleagues, thus I'd prefer not to move the `.cls` file into the texmf directory. As it has worked some time ago (in another but similar template) and also works on my Windows machine, I guess that it should work as expected by me, even if it's not the recommended way to go.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for that resource. I see that this should be fixed in the hotfix `gh422`, but how can I install this hotfix on my machine? Running `tlmgr update --all` does not seem to work.

Comment: Wait until we release it, shouldn't take long.

Comment: Note that we'll fix if for compatibility but the use was never really supported, and by design gives a warning that  `testfolder/testclass` does not match `testclass`  you can make it work without warning in all versions of latex by using `\documentclass{testclass}` and putting `testclass.cls` in the current directory if you don't want to put it in your tex input tree.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand this, but as said, it's more convenient for portable templates. As I packaged some other files together with the `.cls` for my template, the use of a subdirectory is cleaner than having the class in the root directory and including files from the template subdirectory in the document. In the end, the class is a file of the template (and thus, the template subdirectory) too. It's a shame that this is not supported by design.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in comments by members of the LaTeX Project team, calling classes from within subfolders is not an intentionally supported functionality. In the course of the update of LaTeX to version 2020-10-01, this functionality was lost. [A GitHub issue](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/422) pointed out this problem back on October 31, and a bugfix was merged into [hotfix gh422](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/438) for compatibility. However, since this hotfix is not yet available via an update of LaTeX at the time of this post, I tried a workaround that was also recommended in said GitHub issue.

It actually works fine to tell LaTeX a folder within a document where it can search for files. The advantage of this is that you don't have to set this specific folder via TEXINPUTS in your PATH variable for each document. All you have to do is execute the following snippet as the first code in the document so that LaTeX knows the subfolder that contains the class.

```tex
\makeatletter
   \def\input@path{{./style}}
\makeatother
```

Using my initial example, the correct use looks like the following:

Change `test.tex` to:

```tex
\makeatletter
   \def\input@path{{./testfolder}}
\makeatother

\documentclass[optionFalse]{testclass}

\begin{document}
   \texttt{testOption} is set to \texttt{\printtestresult}
\end{document}
```

With this, LaTeX will search also in the `./testfolder` directory for a class named `testclass`.

Comment: +1 sorry for the delay in getting out the update (mostly related to real world issues, not the tex coding)